# blenderproc gives "Exec format error" - Linux

Tags: cycles-render-engine, linux

I'm trying to run blenderproc on a Linux system (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6) and am running into the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error '/home/blender/blender-3.3.0-linux-x64/blender'
```

I've tried installing blenderproc using the pip command:

```
pip install blenderproc
```

and also by cloning it from git as suggested on the [website](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc)

Comment: Since that's an external application and not part of Blender it's probably best to ask about it on the main web site [here](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I just tried running blender and it gives me the same error message. It seems like the issue is with blender

Comment: Assuming that Blender itself is running ok on your Linux version I'd report the error on the app/addon's website.

Comment: I've never been able to run blender on the system. I'm running it on a cluster that does not have a graphic user interface, so I can only run it using blenderproc. However, running blenderproc gives me the above error message. Trying to run blender directly gives me the same error message. So seemingly, the issue lies with blender and not blenderproc